# SQL syntax error - insert into statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Good afternoon all. I've been getting the following error when running the following INSERT INTO statement.

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' , , , , , , , , , )' at line 2

I'm totally stumped. Could this be anything to do with the incremental value I have in my table called 'id'?? Here's the code. Many thanks in advance!!

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","wexdemo");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
$area = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['area']);
$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['postcode']);
$sector = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sector']);
$subsector = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['subsector']);
$contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['contact']);
$position = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['position']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$telephone = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);

$sql="INSERT INTO employers (name, address, area, postcode, sector, subsector, contact, position, email, telephone)
VALUES ($name, $address, $area, $postcode, $sector, $subsector, $contact, $position, $email, $telephone)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: always try to debug your code,you can simply print your query and check what is the actual query that is executing

Comment: learn about prepared statements, it's really clever!

Comment: @PhilHowell: It would be *best*, if working with [*`mysqli_prepare`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.prepare.html)

Answer (score 3):

Insert query **values** should be wrapped inside the `'` single quote or `"`double quotes.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO employers (`name`, `address`, `area`, `postcode`, `sector`, `subsector`, `contact`, `position`, `email`, `telephone`)
 VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$area', '$postcode', '$sector', '$subsector',
       ..^
 '$contact', '$position', '$email', '$telephone')";
```

instead of

```
$sql="INSERT INTO employers (name, address, area, postcode, sector, subsector, contact, position, email, telephone)
VALUES ($name, $address, $area, $postcode, $sector, $subsector, $contact, $position, $email, $telephone)";
```

Comment: Hi Krish, I added the single quotes which took away the error message but the data is not being inserted correctly into the table. The auto incremental "id" column is the only data that appears on each row...

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: @PhilHowell: Before calling `mysqli_query`, debug with `echo $sql;`. That lets you know if proper data is being sent to database.

Comment: @KrishR I'm not sure how to do that. Could you kindly advise?

Comment: Please make sure you run this code only after the form submit, since you have used POST of values.

Comment: try `echo $sql;` after the insert statement to know about the post of values

Comment: I'm getting this now @KrishR ... INSERT INTO employers (name, address, area, postcode, sector, subsector, contact, position, email, telephone) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')

Comment: So it means, POST values are empty.

Comment: @KrishR Could it be the msqli_real_escape_string returning the empty string? I've never used this before but see that it's recommended on W3Schools so have tried it here for the first time.

Comment: That is not problem, add this line and you can know the POST values `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: With the var_dump I can see that the form is posting successfully, however VALUES remains empty... @KrishR

Comment: I've done exactly as advised here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp. Can't see where I'm going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

The values you're inserting need to be in single or double quotes, if their column type is string. Try this code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO employers (name, address, area, postcode, sector, subsector, contact, position, email, telephone)
VALUES ('$name', '$address', '$area', '$postcode', '$sector', '$subsector', '$contact', '$position', '$email', '$telephone')";
```

The only values you probably don't want enclosed in quotes are those who have numeric values - i.e. probably `$postcode` and `$telephone`

Answer (score 0):

Variables should not be included in 'or "; I get the same error even though the query is populated and and looks right
MyError: INSERT INTO dati_modelle VALUES (1, sonia, nota 1, 14, Height, 165, Bust, 60, Waist, 65, Hips, 60, Shoe, 33, Eyes, brown)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, 14, Height, 165, Bust, 60, Waist, 65, Hips, 60, Shoe, 33, Eyes, brown)' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

$sql="INSERT INTO employers (name, address, area, postcode, sector, subsector, contact, position, email, telephone)
VALUES ( " + "" + $name +"" + ", " + "" + $address +"" + ", " + "" + $area  + "" + ", " + ""+  $sector + "" + ", " + ""+
$subsector+ "" + ", " + ""+$contact + "" + ", " + ""+$position +"" + ", " + ""+ $email + "" + ", " + ""+
$telephone + "" + ")";

Comment: If that should be PHP code: please never recommend the usage of such highly insecure code